# Windows Phone 8.1 webview new tab , file explorer isn't working.

Tags: webview, windows-phone-8.1

I'm writing WindowsPhone 8.1 RT app . My mainpage is a webview of teknoseyir.com . This a social website( like facebook-twitter) and you can upload images. I'm having trouble at uploading images and opening new tab. At the other browsers(Chrome ie11 etc.) when user click this image button , phone appearing file explorer for select images but my webview page it isn't working.
[image]

What should i have to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Must be related to this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/6c573f20-76d7-41f9-bcf9-84b962eef5f9/

Also scratching my head.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the button display depends on the UserAgent string, which can be tweaked in the request in order to be shown, however pressing the button will launch the photos picker dialog but after that nothing, will never upload...